# Chaplin and regions

Tags: node.js, chaplinjs

I'd need some help in getting started with node.js and Chaplin

Here's the scenario:

- Client comes to my server
- I serve a static html page to the client. In this html there's a div with and id "test"
- This html also launches the chaplin app
- in my chaplin app, I want to be able to attach an event to the "test" div, e.g clicking the div alerts "Yeah"

How does this work?

For what I've managed to learn by trying (as I don't really find any good instructions on this chaplin..) is that I need to create regions where I then put my views into. These views can only have events inside this region. What I don't get is how do I get to use this "test" div as a region?

**server**

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**Client**

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/app.css">
  <script src="/javascripts/vendor.js"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/app.js"></script>
  <script>require('initialize');</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="test">
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

routes.coffee

```
module.exports = (match) ->
  match '', 'home#index'
```

home-controller.coffee

```
Controller = require 'controllers/base/controller'
HeaderView = require 'views/home/header-view'
HomePageView = require 'views/home/home-page-view'

module.exports = class HomeController extends Controller
  beforeAction: ->
    super
    @compose 'header', HeaderView, region: 'header'

  index: ->
    @view = new HomePageView region: 'main'
```

home-page-view.coffee

```
View = require 'views/base/view'

module.exports = class HomePageView extends View
    autoRender: true
    className: 'home-page'
    template: require './templates/home'
    events:
        'click "testi"': 'testEvent'

    testEvent: (event) ->
        alert "Yeah"
```

Clicking works ok in this HomePageView thing but how could I bind that event to the "test" div in my html, or how could I use already existing divs as regions?

Comment: I'm deeply suspicious of any library whose main selling point is vague promises of "design patterns and best practices". What prompted you to choose Chaplin rather than using, Backbone, jQuery, etc?

Comment: Generally speaking, your view's `render` method will produce some HTML, and the `events` object binds to elements in that HTML. I don't think Chaplin allows you to bind events to elements that are _outside_ your view.

Answer (score 0):

You would add container option to your main layout view, where the value is your dom element e.g. #test.  So it may look something like this.

```
View = require 'views/base/view'

module.exports = class HomePageView extends View
  container: '#test'
  autoRender: true
  className: 'home-page'
  template: require './templates/home'
  events:
    'click "testi"': 'testEvent'

  testEvent: (event) ->
    alert "Yeah"
```

I would also suggest you take a look at this project - https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin-boilerplate.  A nice boilerplate example, should help with your understanding.